# Array of 'a option

Tags: f#

I have a function

```
foo 'a -> 'b option
```

and I have a n array of 'a

```
let data_in: 'a[] = ...
```

I need to get array of 'b.  So I have two question:

1. I want to do something like this:

   ```
   bar(data: 'a []) : 'b [] = 
     data |> foo

   let result : 'b[] = Array.filter (fun e -> 
                                        match e with
                                        | Some(e) -> true
                                        | None -> false)
   ```

but I get the error that `bar` expected type `'b`, but get `'b option`. How can I fix the type declaration in `bar` ?

2. May be there is a way to do all this without `map` + `filter` by one expression ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array.choose` does map + filter in one go.

It is probably the easiest solution for your problem.

Comment: He's working with arrays though, so he might want `Array.choose` instead of `List.choose`. (Otherwise, use `Array.toList`.)